# Post the message using MSTeams Graph with a different user name

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We are using `POST /teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) to post the message to the particular channel.

When the message is posted it shows the 'User Name' of the User who posted the message.

Is that possible to change the 'User Name' to something else while posting the message using Graph API ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name can not be modified. Best way is to create a bot and handle it through bot.

Comment: Thanks. We have to post message that comes from an external server periodically. Does proactive messages  [Proactive Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-proactive-messages?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) serve the purpose ?

If so could you please provide additional docs and samples ?